# is it possible to locate file on Mac without knowing exact location?

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-io, itunes

I am trying to locate a file on Machintosh without knowing exact file location. I am developing an app which needs to locate iTunes library XML file and parse it for data. However XML resides in,

```
/Users/**Current logged in username**/Music/iTunes
```

Now username may change, So how to set path of let my code find below named file programmatically. Language used is Objective - C.

```
File name : iTunes Music Library.xml
```

> Possible solution I thought is to get username by code. Is there any method which returns a string of current logged in user's "username".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `~/Music/iTunes`. `~` represents the home directory of the current user.

Or you could could see this question: [Mac OS X: Get current username and home directory for current user from Directory Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262426/mac-os-x-get-current-username-and-home-directory-for-current-user-from-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this! The user's iTunes library doesn't have to be in the default location.

Instead, read the iTunesRecentDatabasePaths key from com.apple.iapps. It'll give you an array that represents the recently used iTunes libraries.

```
$ defaults read com.apple.iapps iTunesRecentDatabasePaths
(
    "/Volumes/Media/iTunes/iTunes Library.xml"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

NSHomeDirectory() is a Foundation function that returns an NSString of the path to the current user's home directory.

[Apple Developer Library - NSHomeDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory)